# Expression illegal in evaluator (& Access Violation)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, access-violation

Im trying to process a plain text file (loaded into a StringList), by using class Tbb2uc but getting AV at calling function GetAddress.

```
  TArrayQuotePositions = array[1..4] of integer;

  Tbb2uc = class(TObject)
  private
    Farrayquotes: TArrayQuotePositions;
    SlInput: TStringList;
    Inputfilename: TFileName;
    SlOutput: TStringList;
    function GetQuotePositions( aLine: string ): TArrayQuotePositions;
    function GetInvoice( aLine: string ): string;
    function GetName( aLine: string ): string;
    function GetAddress( aLine: string ): string;
    function GetSwift( aLine: string ): string;
    function ProcessSl: integer;        
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function OpenFile: integer;
  end;
```

---

```
function Tbb2uc.GetInvoice( aLine: string ): string;
var
  quotesPos: TArrayQuotePositions;
begin
  quotesPos := GetQuotePositions( aLine );
  result := copy( aLine, quotesPos[3]+1, (quotesPos[4]-quotesPos[3])-1 );
end;
```

---

```
function Tbb2uc.GetName( aLine: string ): string;  
var
  quotesPos: TArrayQuotePositions;
begin
  quotesPos := GetQuotePositions( aLine );
  result := copy( aLine, quotesPos[3]+1, (quotesPos[4]-quotesPos[3])-1 );
end;
```

---

The execution does not even jump into the function. I get the AV at calling this function.

```
function Tbb2uc.GetAddress( aLine: string ): string;
var
  quotesPos: TArrayQuotePositions;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
begin
  quotesPos := GetQuotePositions( aLine );
  address1 := copy( aLine, quotesPos[1]+1, (quotesPos[2]-quotesPos[1])-1 );
  address2 := copy( aLine, quotesPos[3]+1, (quotesPos[4]-quotesPos[3])-1 );
  result := address1 + ' ' + address2;
end;
```

---

Using the above functions:

```
function Tbb2uc.ProcessSl: integer;
var
  i: integer;
  line: string;
  invoice,name,addr,swift: string;
begin
  SlInput.LoadFromFile( string(Inputfilename) );
  //
  for i := 0 to SlInput.Count -1 do begin
    if ansipos( STARTSTRING, SlInput[i]) <> 0 then begin
      invoice := GetInvoice(SlInput[i]);
      name := GetName(SlInput[i+1]);
      ////
      addr := GetAddress(SlInput[i+2]); //Access Violation
      ////
      swift := GetSwift(SlInput[i+4]);
      line := line + invoice + ';' + name + ';' + addr + ';' + swift;
    end;
    SlOutput.Add(line);
    line := '';
  end;
  SlOutput.SaveToFile( OUTPUT_FNAME );
end;
```

The execution is ok until calling GetAddress. At debugging, when evaluate SlInput[i+2], i get 'Expression illegal in evaluator' and right now i have no idea. As you see im only processing the lines of the stringlist.

Comment: Please show an MCVE rather than having us guess what your code is.

Comment: Agreed.  It could be anything at this point... maybe you're loading a file into a freed stringlist - how can we know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing your stringlist out of bounds.

```
for i := 0 to SlInput.Count -1 do begin

 // ...(etc)

      addr := GetAddress(SlInput[i+2]);
```

`i` is running to the full size of the list.  You are indexing two higher than that.

Comment: At debugging, the value of counter i is only 9. In the stringlist i have more than 800 lines.

Comment: yes but the effect 'will' arise later (wont because im gonna correct this of course). But thanks for the forewarm.

Answer (score -1):

It was a static array that i was over-indexing. The debugger cannot pinpoint the exact line so it was not obvious (for me):

```
function Tbb2uc.GetQuotePositions( aLine: string ): TArrayQuotePositions;
var
  i: integer;
  arraypos: integer;
begin
  for i := low(TArrayQuotePositions) to high(TArrayQuotePositions) do begin
    Farrayquotes[i] := 0;
  end;
  arraypos := low(TArrayQuotePositions);
  for i := 1 to length(aLine) do begin
    if aLine[i] = CHAR_FOR_COLLECT then begin         
      Farrayquotes[arraypos] := i;  //over-indexing, Farrayquotes: TArrayQuotePositions = array[1..4] of integer;
      inc(arraypos);            
    end;
  end;
  result := Farrayquotes;
end;
```

Sorry... indeed my question was far from complete.

Comment: This code bears no relation to the question that was asked. The real lesson to learn is to debug a bit before asking, and when you do ask prepare a clean MCVE.

Comment: An abject lesson on why you really need to leave range checking turned on.